# Count three posibilities in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with subscribers which have two fields, actived and suscribed. I need to get the total number of subscribers, the number of activated and the number of suscribed in the same consult. I've tried to do this with a double left join but i need to group by a field that is not the primary key and i get error. I have my consult now like this:

````
FROM (SELECT subscribers.mailing_list, subscribers.mailing_list AS suscriptores, s2.inactivos AS inactivos, s3.excluidos AS excluidos
FROM subscribers
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, mailing_list, COUNT(*) AS inactivos FROM subscribers WHERE subscribed = false GROUP BY id) s2 ON subscribers.id = s2.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, mailing_list, COUNT(*) AS excluidos FROM subscribers WHERE excluded = true GROUP BY id) s3 ON subscribers.id = s3.id
) AS subs
GROUP BY subs.mailing_list```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of needing 3 queries, you need `case expressions` inside an aggregate function, this is known as "conditional aggregates" e.g.

```
SELECT
        mailing_list
      , COUNT( CASE WHEN subscribed = FALSE THEN 1 END ) AS inactivos
      , COUNT( CASE WHEN subscribed = TRUE  THEN 1 END ) AS excluidos
      , COUNT( * ) AS Total
FROM subscribers
GROUP BY
        mailing_list
```

Comment: Excelente! ( *but I did get confused with the Spanish labels* :)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can simplify this logic to:

```
SELECT mailing_list,
       SUM( subscribed = FALSE ) AS inactivos,
       SUM( subscribed = TRUE ) AS excluidos,
       COUNT( * ) AS Total
FROM subscribers
GROUP BY mailing_list;
```

If `subscribed` is  in fact `boolean`, you can further simplify this to:

```
SELECT mailing_list,
       SUM( NOT subscribed ) AS inactivos,
       SUM( subscribed ) AS excluidos,
       COUNT( * ) AS Total
FROM subscribers
GROUP BY mailing_list;
```

Comment: Yes, this is another solution but i prefer to have 0 intead of null

Comment: @DonProtón . . . How do you get `NULL` from these?  The only way would be if `subscribed` is `NULL`, which seems problematic in other ways.